# Dependent probability in Python

Tags: python, probability

I'm trying to make something in Python, just for myself, which will determine the likelihood of, in my case, drawing a certain card in a deck. The deck's size is determine by a raw_input, as is the number of cards of which you are trying to calculate probability of drawing. Right now, I have:

```
from __future__ import division

t = True
while True:
    if t == True:
        numCards = int(raw_input("How many cards in your deck? Type here: "))

        print "There are " + str(numCards) + " cards in your deck."

        whatCards = raw_input("What card are you testing for how likely it is to draw them? Type here: ")
        whatCards = whatCards.capitalize()
        print whatCards + " is a great card!"

        if whatCards.endswith("s"):
            numCards2 = int(raw_input("How many " + whatCards + " are in it? "))
            whatCards = whatCards + "s"
        elif whatCards.endswith("y"):
            numCards2 = int(raw_input("How many " + whatCards[:-1] + "ies are in it? "))
        else:
            numCards2 = int(raw_input("How many " + whatCards + "s are in it?"))

        if numCards2 > 1:
            print "Ok! There are " + str(numCards2) + " " + whatCards + "s" + "!"
        else:
            print "Alright. There is " + str(1) + " " + whatCards + "!"



        '''probability = (numCards2 / numCards) + (numCards2 / (numCards-1)) + (numCards2 / (numCards-2)) + \


(numCards2 / (numCards-3)) + (numCards2 / (numCards-4)) + (numCards2 / (numCards-5))\
                  + (numCards2 / (numCards-6))'''
    probability = numCards2 / numCards

    print "Results are approximate"
    print "Decimal: " + str(probability)

    if len(str(probability)) <= 3:
        print "Percentage: " + str(probability)[2] + str(0) + "%"
    else:
        print "Percentage: " + str(probability)[2] + str(probability)[3] + "%"

    print "Fraction: " + str(numCards2) + "/" + str(numCards)
    t = False

if t == False:
    numCards = int(raw_input("How many cards in your deck? Type here: "))

    print "There are " + str(numCards) + " cards in your deck."

    whatCards = raw_input("What card are you testing for how likely it is to draw them? Type here: ")
    whatCards = whatCards.capitalize()
    print whatCards + " is a great card!"

    if whatCards.endswith("s"):
        numCards2 = int(raw_input("How many " + whatCards + " are in it? "))
        whatCards = whatCards + "s"
    elif whatCards.endswith("y"):
        numCards2 = int(raw_input("How many " + whatCards[:-1] + "ies are in it? "))
    else:
        numCards2 = int(raw_input("How many " + whatCards + "s are in it?"))

    if numCards2 > 1:
        print "Ok! There are " + str(numCards2) + " " + whatCards + "s" + "!"
    else:
        print "Alright. There is " + str(1) + " " + whatCards + "!"



    '''probability = (numCards2 / numCards) + (numCards2 / (numCards-1)) + (numCards2 / (numCards-2)) + \
                  (numCards2 / (numCards-3)) + (numCards2 / (numCards-4)) + (numCards2 / (numCards-5))\
                  + (numCards2 / (numCards-6))'''
    probability = numCards2 / numCards

    print "Results are approximate"
    print "Decimal: " + str(probability)

    if len(str(probability)) <= 3:
        print "Percentage: " + str(probability)[2] + str(0) + "%"
    else:
        print "Percentage: " + str(probability)[2] + str(probability)[3] + "%"

    print "Fraction: " + str(numCards2) + "/" + str(numCards)
    t = True
```

As you can see, what it's currently solving is likelihood of only **one** draw. However, my goal is to make it so that the user can input their own number of card draws, so, say, they have a 60 card deck, with 15 Swamp cards in it, and 7 draws. The problem is that if I wanted to draw a hand's worth of cards (7), I couldn't just make it calculate the probability of drawing out of 60, then 59, then 58, down to 53. That's because if they were to draw the Swamp, the probability goes down, which going down from 60 to 53 wouldn't do. What would I have to make so that it randomly selected x cards out of y (deck size), with z amount of draws as well as decremented the number of x when it was "drawn", and changed y for each "draw". And it would have to work any number of times, depending on what the user wanted. Thanks! (hope this makes sense...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have n cards and you are drawing m of them. The possible combinations are n!/(n-m)! If you are looking for the probability to draw y cards ( y<=m ) of a kind which makes up x of the total n cards. You have to consider 2 quantities:
1. The possible ways to pick y cards out of x cards which is x!/(x-y)! And then the possible ways to lay this ordered sets into m slots, or else where to put the other m-y cards into the set of m cards which is m!/(m-y)! 
The product of these 2 quantities gives you the favorable events, while the first number gives you the total event. So your probability is

P = x!m!(n-m)!/(n!(x-y)!(m-y)!)

I hope I did not miss anything :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just curious, what does the '!' do?

Comment: Is there supposed to be something instead of the !'s? I'm in Python, by the way, and it's throwing a syntax error on the !.

Comment: its a factorial 5! = 5x4x3x2x1 in python is `math.factorial(x)`